# is there some Wordpress template shortcode for javascript files?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know we can get some path with `<?php bloginfo('something');?>` into php files, but is it some equivalent for javascript file loaded with the `enqueue_script` function ?
Did wordpress change some shortcode into those files ?

**EDIT :** I think I did not clearly express my needs. So i want to know if wordpress had some shortcode who, placed into a js file who is loaded with the enqueue method, will be replaced by the template path. Typically i need to make some ajax call form a .php file from my template and want to avoid hard linking file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No javascript files won't be parsed as php, and as such won't process any shortcodes or php.

Why not just make your links relative. Often I find subdomaining my dev copy, removes any problems when moving a site live and broken links.

You could cheat and link to a php file, which then passes header information as Javascript. Doesn't seem very elegant though. See [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/externalphp.shtml).

Or you could just declare the variable in a little bit of inline Javascript and pick it up in the external JS file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var siteURL= '<?php bloginfo('url');?>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourscript.js"></script>
```

Then in yourscript.js just reference the variable 'siteURL'

Comment: That's a kind of solution that i finaly use, put the script who store the variable into functions.php and add it to the init state. So the variable will be available for all my scripts but i don't like the way too much. With this, any script (so anyone) can use the variable (and see i register it) ...

i Hope to find a better, more elegant solution. Thx btw :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to register scripts using [wp_register_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script). Then by placing wp_enqueue_script before wp_head() it will load them in for you. The idea of using wp_enqueue_script is that you don't need to enter them all in manually, and you can load other scripts depending on whether a certain script has been loaded.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but that's not the point,  i want to know if wordpress had some shortcode who, placed into a js file who is loaded with the enqueue method, will be replaced by the template path. Typically i need to make some ajax call form a .php file from my template and want to avoid hard linking file

Comment: I'm still not sure you're question is explained very well - I'll leave it for someone else to try and help!